# Ruby on Rails Custom Controller Action for Users Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

Working on versions:
Ruby: 3.0.2
Rails 6.1.4

I'm trying to put a button in my View template for "Users" that will set the :mod attribute to false, with the button just being "Demote User".

I had it working SOMEHOW using a helper method, demote_user, and some variation of

```
  <% if logged_in? && current_user.admin? %>
      <%= link_to "Demote User", user_path(@user), onclick: demote_user(@user), class: "btn btn-info" %>
  <% end %>
```

I messed up however it was working when trying to move this method into a controller for best practice. I'm not sure what format worked out, but I've tried many such as

```
 :onclick => demote_user(@user)
 onclick: 'demote_user(@user)'
 onclick=demote_user(@user)
 onclick='demote_user(@user)
```

and etc. Somehow, it did eventually work but I busted it. Now, every time I load the User's page, it's just executing demote_user(@user) without even needing to click the button, so refreshing a User's page is demoting them.

I am now trying to do this properly by creating a demote method in the UserController, but I have NO IDEA how to make the route, or make it work properly. Up until now, all my routes have been working using resources, and the basic new, create, destroy, etc.

I've been trying many different routes, and view formatting, with no luck and usually ending up with just: Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/demote.3"

I'd like to be able to avoid using the Javascript onClick functionality and do it properly with the controller even if I could remember how to make it work, but I think my route, or view page, or controller is incorrect. Here are the contents of each file:

Controller

```
def demote
  byebug
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.mod = false
  redirect_to user_path(@user)
end
```

View

```
div class="container text-center mt-4">
  <% if logged_in? && current_user.admin? %>
      <%= link_to "Demote User", demote_path(@user), class: "btn btn-info" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#home'
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  resources :articles
  get 'signup', to: 'users#new'
  resources :users, except: [:new]
  get 'login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post 'login', to: 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :categories
  post 'demote', to: 'users#demote'
end
```

Up until now, I've been following a course, and I've nailed everything in it and have added some of my own functionality, but I'm still not quite sure how to make sense of routes, or what paths it creates.

I'd like to make other similar custom controller functions beyond show, index, create, delete, update which are all I really understand how to build. I'm not even sure if POST is the correct call in the route.

Comment: look at your routes by pointing a browser to `localhost:3000/routes` what is the name of the route (left column) that refers to 'demote'? What error are you seeing? What do you see in the log file when the request is received?

Comment: Using `onclick` like that won't actually work since you are making a fundamental (and very common) beginner mistake where you're not properly mentally separating what happens on the server and client side. `onclick: demote_user(@user)` will call the method when the view is rendered on the server (ooops!) not when the user clicks the button. For that to actually work you would need to pass the name of a javascript function which sends an ajax request (tons of tutorials for this).

Comment: POST also isn't quite correct since its used to create resources. `PATCH /users/1/demote` would be better and can be generated with `resources :users, except: [:new] do; patch :demote; end`. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions

Answer (score 1):

I would just setup an additional [RESTful action for the resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions):

```
resources :users do
  patch :demote
end
```

```
<% if logged_in? && current_user.admin? %>
  <%= button_to "Demote User", demote_user_path(@user), method: :patch %>
<% end %>
```

You can use `link_to` instead of `button_to` but you need to use the correct `method: :patch` or `data: { turbo_method: :patch }` option depending on your version of Rails to get the javascript driver to do its trickery.

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me get further along with the situation. I'm hitting my byebug when I click the button now, but I'm still getting: 


ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#demote
Couldn't find User without an ID

However, when I check params in byebug right before 
```
@user = User.find(params{:id])
``` I have all the information about the user, including the user_id. If I change it to 

@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
, this actually works, but I thought I just needed params[:id]), so I'm confused.

Comment: It's working out well with your example, and I even added promote as an option, which I achieved with
`resources :users do
  patch :demote
  patch :promote
end`
but I also needed to add:
`resources :users, except: [:new] do
    member do
      get 'demote'
      get 'promote'
    end
  end`
in order to make it work. Is there a cleaner way to do this than two separate blocks?

I'm trying to make sense of your direct reply above to make it work, and it does look like it's doable from your example.

Comment: I was able to get it in one block of code using your awesome example, I really appreciate it! I settled on:

resources :users, except: [:new] do
    member do
      get 'demote'
      get 'promote'
    end
    patch :promote
    patch :demote
  end

I can't upvote your answer because I'm so new, but you were extremely helpful!! I also cannot figure out how to make the block quote in comments :(

Comment: You can use `patch :demote, on: :member` instead of using `member do ... end`. You can also accept the answer by hitting the checkmark next to the upvote button which will give you a small amount of rep and mark the question as answered.